# How to list Taxonomy Terms with Pictures in View?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I want to create a View with the list of Taxonomy Terms in Drupal 7.
I edit the taxonomy content type so that it has 1 extra image field.

I want to show all Taxonomy terms with their image but I cant seem to find it anywhere in View options.
[image: Screen shot]

Comment: Is it the taxonomy terms which you want to show together with their image field or is it content that you have tagged with terms?

Comment: I want to show the taxonomy Terms with images. I will use it as a menu(example: http://www.hercocuk.org/index.php?kategori=3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the view, you need to create a view of taxonomy terms instead of of content/nodes like you have done in your SS above. Then you have all the fields etc available that you have on your terms.

[image]

Comment: Thx a lot @googletorp, thats exactly what I was missing :)